# ¿Existe una onomatopeya para el sonido de la "risa" de una hiena?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, animales, onomatopeyas

¿Existe una onomatopeya para el sonido que emiten las hienas para comunicarse, que usualmente se asocia con el sonido de una risa humana?

Comment: Excelente pregunta! de botepronto se me ocurre "*Juaar Juar Juar*" recuerdo haberlo visto usado en un comic alguna vez, sin embargo me es imposible localizar la referencia en google images. Si doy con ella la ofrecere como respuesta, mientras tanto **Juar Juar Juar** podria ser la onomatopeya candidato salvo alguna mejor

Comment: He visto en un par de sitios ya que sonido de la hiena se denomina [aullido o risa](https://lenguayliteraturap.blogspot.com.es/2016/02/los-sonidos-de-los-animales-onomatopeyas.html). Podrías combinar el "auu" del aullido con el "ja" de la risa: "juau", "jua", "jau" o combinaciones similares te podrían valer.

Comment: Tal vez se generacional esto, pero entre mas lo pienso, mas estoy seguro que la onomatopeya adecuanda es "Mufasa"... cfr: https://youtu.be/ilPHdDIPKeM

Comment: Encontré esto, no sé que validez tendrá https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gGkbnLAglk

Comment: me gustaria usar "hie hie hie hie hie"  , sobre todo por que a la hora de escribir me gusta jugar con los sonidos, por ser hie de hiena

Comment: @Charlie Yo también encontré en varios sitios lo de *aullido, risa* en las hienas pero entiendo que se refiere a dos sonidos distintos que hace, igual que en gato aparece *maullido, bufido, ronroneo*

Comment: @yotanka pero la de la hiena no aparece en esa lista

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay unos ejemplos en la literatura:

> <sup><sub>RAMON</sub></sup>.- Tiene razón Adela. Así, cuando lleguéis a casa, de vuelta, tu maridito... **¡Ji, ji, ji!**... *(La risa de la hiena, imitando a su mujer)* ¿Verdad, Adela?
>
> <sup><sub>ADELA</sub></sup>.- ¡Claro que sí! **¡Ji, ji, ji!**...
>
> - [*Cuidado con él de los cuernos!: tres mujeres y el diablo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5PsdAQAAIAAJ&q=%22hiena%22+risa), Sigfrido Blasco, Adrían Ortega

> "¡Más rápido, más rápido!... **Ji-Ji-Ji**." , se reía como hiena;
>
> - [*La dulce espera*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=g8H-LglfpCYC&pg=PA57&dq=hiena+%22je,+je,+je%22), Frederic Luján

> —**Ji, ji, ji; je, je, je**...
>
> Por la puerta misma del sueno, entró la Muerte.
>
> —Buenas, amiga hiena.
>
> - [*Relatos de La Costa de Los Esclavos*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2pQfAQAAIAAJ&dq=hiena+%22je%2C+je%2C+je%22), Lirca Vallés Calaña

> **¡Je, je, je!**, rio como una hiena.
>
> - [*Los imprescindibles: La novela de los últimos maquis*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C7caDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT377&dq=hiena+je+je+je), Raimundo Castro

> Hace cinco meses que dejó de trabajar, pero por un error sigue cobrando —y soltaba una risa sardónica, **je, je, je,** como la de las hienas...
>
> - [*Las Cosas Más Extrañas*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=F0xfAAAAMAAJ&q=hiena+%22je,+je,+je%22), Andrés Trapiello

> D<sup><sub>OÑA</sub></sup> H<sup><sub>IENA</sub></sup>
> ¡Ah sí, tú! No sueñes. Ya te veo de rey de la selva, **ja, ja, ja.** Te verías muy guapo con tu capa roja; como que hace juego con tu piel, **ja, ja, ja, ja.**
>
> - [Teatro de humor para jóvenes](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=v-ObqHLwrIMC&pg=PA48&dq=hiena+%22ja,+ja,+ja%22) (*El bocón*, María Auxilio Ballinas)

> [image]
>
> - [*La cosa que más duele del mundo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nlJKRd5zmWMC&pg=PT10&dq=%22hiena%22+ja+ja+ja), Paco Liván

> Miren al tigre, nos hace ¡grr! Miren al lobo, que nos hace ¡auuuuu!, y miren la hiena, **¡jua jua jua!** Vean al elefante, que nos hace ¡ahr! Vean a ese changuito, que nos hace ¡yiyi! Vean al jabalí, que nos hace ¡oiing!, y vean la cebra, ¡ha ha ha ha!
>
> - [*Guía del Maestro Español 3: Voces de infancia*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdo0yWCD30UC&pg=PT54&dq=%22ha,+ha,+ha%22+hiena), Antonio Domínguez Hidalgo

> **¡Juá juá juá!** — exclamó la hiena — . Nosotros que somos tan felices tenemos que depender de este bigotudo.
>
> - [*Las repeticiones y otros relatos inéditos*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=slplAAAAMAAJ&q=%22jua,+jua,+jua%22+hiena), Silvina Ocampo

> HIENA: **Juar, juar, juar.** ¡No es justo!
>
> - [*Tramoya: cuaderno de teatro, Números 42-45*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DpfsAAAAMAAJ&q=juar+hiena), Universidad Veracruzana

Y además, esta representación 'interesante' del siglo XIX:

> [image]
>
> - [*Juegos de prendas*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-IYKAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA125&dq=hiena), Ramón Campuzano (1853)

Pero así que son muy infrecuentes y diversos (en realización de la vocal), parece que no hay una onomatopeya canónica (ni común) para el sonido que hacen los hienas, por consiguiente se puede usar cualquier onomatopeya de la risa humana.

<sup>**Nota:** No obstante [sí son comunes](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Lista_de_voces_de_animales) los verbos *aullar* y *reír* y los sonidos *aullido* y *risa*.</sup>